# Почему строка "/// " выделяется в редакторе

Tags: visual-studio

Конкретно Visual Studio отображает тройной слеш темно-зеленым (обычные комментарии ярче).
Это какая-то специальная пометка вроде "// TODO" или что?

Comment: у меня vs17 тройной слеш темно зеленым не выделяет.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

xml комментарии
например

```
  /// <summary>
  /// описание класса 
  /// так же есть теги для описания входных параметров и возвращаемого значения
  /// </summary>
  public class Temperature
```